# PLC Motor Control

Tags: power-supply, motor-controller, plc

Im trying to control the speed of 2 brushed motors with a click plc, I'm using 2 seperate power supplies, 1 for the plc, and 1 for the Motors. Is there any way to alter the voltage supplied to the motors using the plc's analog output?

Comment: The power supply for the motor must have an adjustment feature that can be commanded using an output from the PLC. For good motor performance, purchase an electronic speed controller ESC for each motor.Select ESCs that have speed command inputs that are compatible with the PLC or vice versa.

Comment: I think you mean "Click PLC". Capitals matter as in this case they would indicate that you are referring to a branded product.

Answer (score 0):

The analogue output on PLC indeed has voltage, however, the purpose is not to fully power up the motor. The analogue output on PLC is used to control/manipulate/alter the outcome, in motor case, it can be used to alter the speed by varying the voltage from 0-high voltage. I see you use two power supplies separately, my suggestion is, if both PLC and motor require same Voltage and current, you can use one power supply and power them in parallel. Don’t forget to attach motor driver on PLC, it is for programming the motor itself.